# Product Price showing as 0 (Zero) on Products List and Home page

Tags: price, custom-options

Our products purchase option starts from **10 grams / .35 oz** to **1 KG / 35 oz** with different pricing option for different weight. We do not have a base price so the base price of the product is set to 0.

Then we have created custom options from 10 grams / .35 oz to 1 KG / 35 oz with different pricing.

Now the issue is that the price of 10 grams / .35 oz shows up fine in the product view page but it is showing as 0 (Zero) on products list and home page.

[image: Product view page price]

[image: Product List Page]

How can I resolve this issue?